# Write in many to many relationship table with only primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables like this:

[image]

And between these tables there is a Junction table like this:

```
*appartiene_squadra*
field name (**primary key**)(*foreign key to first table*)
field name (**primary key**)(*foreign key to second table*)
```

Now, the problem is that the model recognize only the first two tables and I can't write data in appartiene_squadra. **How I can write data here?**

Comment: In short: you don't. EF has abstracted the junction table away, so you 'write in that table' by writing related entities in the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in identifying that Entity Framework creates the junction table for you.

To enter data, you do not "add data to the junction table". What you do is add data *to the navigational property*, which will automatically be stored in the junction table by Entity Framework.

```
using(var db = new MyDataContext())
{
    Installatori myInstallatori = db.GetExistingInstallatori(); //Assume this gives you an existing entity
    Squadra mySquadra = db.GetExistingSquadra(); //Assume this gives you an existing entity

    //You can do it this way
    myInstallatori.squadra.Add(mySquadra);

    //or this way
    mySquadra.installatori.Add(myInstallatori);

    //And then you save it to the database
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I've shown an example of adding A to B, and B to A. Please note that **you should only do one of these at the same time** (at least when it is your intention to *save to the database*, rather than simply populating the entity in memory).

Also, to remove a row from the database:

```
mySquadra.installatori.Remove(myInstallatori);

db.SaveChanges();
```